# Auto play/pause and restart TiltSlider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I want to achieve a slider pause on mouse over and resume it on mouse out.

This is my code which autoplays the slider:

```
<script src="<?=$prelink?>addon/slider/js/classie.js"></script>
<script src="<?=$prelink?>addon/slider/js/tiltSlider.js"></script>
<script src="<?=$prelink?>js/jslink.js"></script>
<script>
  new TiltSlider( document.getElementById( 'slideshow' ) );               
  var intervalId = window.setInterval(function timerfun(){              
    $('nav>.current').next().trigger('click');
      if($('nav > .current').next().index() == '-1'){
        $('nav > span').trigger('click');
      }
    }, 11000); 
</script>
```

Please help me to achieve this. I have tried this code:

```
$('#slideshow').on("mouseover",function(){
  clearInterval(intervalID);
});

$('.image_thumb ul li').on("mouseout",function(){
  intervalID = setInterval(cycleImage, slidetime);
});
```

But the code is not working as TiltSlider behaves unexpectedly.

Comment: This feature exists in a popular opensource package called OwlCarousel. [Here is a link to their javascript](https://github.com/OwlFonk/OwlCarousel/blob/master/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js), where you can search for their handler for stopping the slider on mouseover. Search for `stop : function` to see their handler.

Comment: i am using titleslider and can not switch ..

Comment: I didn't ask you to switch. I said read their source code to see how they implemented the pause on mouseover feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should accomplish what you are trying to do:

```
<script>

    new TiltSlider(document.getElementById('slideshow'));

    $(function() {

        var cycleTime = 1000;//11000;
        var intervalId;

        function cycleImage () {
            $('nav>.current').next().trigger('click');
            if ($('nav > .current').next().index() == '-1') {
                $('nav > span').trigger('click');
            }
        };

        $('#slideshow').on("mouseover", function() {
            clearInterval(intervalId);
        });

        $('#slideshow').on("mouseout", function() {
            clearInterval(intervalId);
            intervalId = setInterval(cycleImage, cycleTime);
        });

        intervalId = setInterval(cycleImage, cycleTime);
    });

</script>
```